# Connecting eclipse to phpmyadmin XAMPP

Tags: eclipse, phpmyadmin, xampp, mysql-connector

[project picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CYNv8.png)

Hi,

I hope I will ask my question correctly. I don't want to be restriced from asking questions here at stackoverflow.

I opened a new project with eclipse and tried to connect to the XAMPP phpmyadmin database and tried to integrate a mysqlconnector.jar into the project but this does not work and I got the exception:

```
Error java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: /com/mysql/jdbc/Driver
```

I am not sure how the connection between the mysqlconnector and the phpmyadmin works.

Thanks in advance.